# Collection with Traits that return Self

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to have a collection of objects that implement a particular trait.

If I use a trait that returns a value, this works

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

struct World {
    entities: Vec<usize>,
    database: BTreeMap<usize, Box<ReadValue>>,
    //database : BTreeMap<usize,Box<ReadEcs>>, // Doesn't work
}

struct SourceInputGateway {
    entity_id: usize,
}

trait ReadValue {
    fn read(&self) -> f32;
}

impl ReadValue for SourceInputGateway {
    fn read(&self) -> f32 {
        0.0
    }
}
```

But if I want to return `Self` as a value then this doesn't work, either as a method template param or associated type

```
trait ReadEcs {
    type T;
    fn read(&self) -> &Self::T;
}

impl ReadEcs for SourceInputGateway {
    type T = SourceInputGateway;
    fn read(&self) -> &Self::T {
        self
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is have a map of types that implement `ReadEcs`, the concrete type of which is not important.

**Further clarification edit**

If I expand the example by adding

```
// Different sized type
struct ComputeCalculator {
    entity_id : usize,
    name : String,
}

impl ReadValue for ComputeCalculator {
    fn read(&self) -> f32 {
        1230.0
    }
}
```

then I can do this

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn read_write() {
        let mut world = World::new();
        world.database.insert(0,Box::new(SourceInputGateway{ entity_id : 1}));
        world.database.insert(2,Box::new(ComputeCalculator{ entity_id : 2 , name : "foo".into() }));

        for (k,ref v) in world.database {
            let item : &Box<ReadValue> = v;
            item.read();
        }

    }
}
```

but if I change or add a trait method that returns Self, I can't do this.
I'd like to understand a way to get around it without unsafe pointers.

Comment: Rust is a statically typed language. Each expression has a type known at compile time. Let's assume the compiler allowed trait objects of type `Box<dyn ReadEcs>`, and you have such a trait object in the variable `x`. Now what is the type of the expression `x.read()`? Trying to answer this question should make clear why this does not work, and also gives hints how to work around the problem. (See also the [definition of object safety in the language reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety).)

Comment: @sven I understand that. But the above example is saying as long as all structs have a `read()` method we can indeed put them in a collection. The test code works fine and returns 0,123 respectively as you'd expect.

Comment: I'm a little confused. It doesn't make much sense to say that "all structs have a `read()` method". The `read()` methods of the two different traits are completely unrelated to each other. The important question to ask is whether the structs implement a particular trait. You can have a collection of trait objects for an object-safe trait, but you can't have such a collection for a trait that is not object-safe. If your `read()` method returns an associated type, you need to specify that type to be able to create a trait object – `Box<dyn ReadEcs<T = f32>>` should be valid.

Comment: Your constraints directly contradict each other (which you acknowledge). To find a solution, you need to explain which parts of the constraints can be flexible, or take a step back to the underlying requirements to reevaluate from there.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this a little more and I think it's possible to solve this while retaining all the advantages of type safety and contiguous storage.

Defining a entity manager with pointers to storage

```
struct Entities {
    entities: Vec<usize>,
    containers: Vec<Box<Storage>>,
}
```

The components themselves that store data related to behaviour

```
struct Position {
    entity_id: usize,
    position: f32,
}

struct Velocity {
    entity_id: usize,
    velocity: f32,
}
```

We will have many instances of components, so we need a contiguous memory store, accessed by an index.

```
struct PositionStore {
    storage: Vec<Position>,
}

struct VelocityStore {
    storage: Vec<Velocity>,
}



trait Storage {
    // Create and delete instances of the component
    fn allocate(&mut self, entity_id: usize) -> usize;

    // Interface methods that would correspond to a base class in C++
    fn do_this(&self);
    // fn do_that(&self);
}
```

The trait for the store implements an `arena` style storage plus the methods it would pass to to the components. This would likely be in the "System" part of an ECS but is left as an exercise for later.

I would like a hint as to how to pass a Fn() that constructs a custom object to the `allocate()` method. I've not figured that out yet.

```
impl Storage for PositionStore {
    fn allocate(&mut self, entity_id: usize) -> usize {
        self.storage.push(Position {
            entity_id,
            position: 0.0,
        });
        self.storage.len() - 1
    }

    fn run(&self) {
        self.storage.iter().for_each(|item| { println!("{}",item.position); });
    }
}

impl Storage for VelocityStore {
    fn allocate(&mut self, entity_id: usize) -> usize {
        self.storage.push(Velocity {
            entity_id,
            velocity: 0.0,
        });
        self.storage.len() - 1
    }

    fn do_this(&self) {
        self.storage.iter().for_each(|item| { println!("{}",item.velocity); });
    }
}
```

Some boiler plate.

```
impl Default for PositionStore {
    fn default() -> PositionStore {
        PositionStore {
            storage: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}

impl Default for VelocityStore {
    fn default() -> VelocityStore {
        VelocityStore {
            storage: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}
```

I think this could be thought about a little more. It stores the relationship between the storage of the components and their position

Instead of `T::default()`, you may want to pass a lambda function that has a specific initialisation for each of your components

```
impl Entities {
    fn register<T>(&mut self) -> usize
    where
        T: Storage + Default + 'static,
    {
        self.containers.push(Box::new(T::default()));
        self.containers.len() - 1
    }

    fn create<T>(&mut self, entity_id: usize, id: usize) -> usize {
        self.containers[id].allocate(entity_id)
    }

    fn run_loop(&self) {
        self.containers.iter().for_each(|x| x.do_this());
    }
}
```

A test case to see if this works

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn arbitary() {
        let mut entities = Entities {
            entities: Vec::new(),
            containers: Vec::new(),
        };
        let velocity_store_id = entities.register::<VelocityStore>();
        let position_store_id = entities.register::<PositionStore>();

        let _ = entities.create::<Velocity>(123, velocity_store_id);
        let _ = entities.create::<Velocity>(234, velocity_store_id);
        let _ = entities.create::<Position>(234, position_store_id);
        let _ = entities.create::<Position>(567, position_store_id);

        entities.run_loop();
    }
}
```